# how to manipulate json objects in javascripts/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wanted to add delete update elements in json using jquery/javascript and when the file submit is done to the server wanted to consider the latest json object.

Can you suggest and approach i am stuck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify to manipulate.

```
json_flat = '{"page":"1","total":"2","ids":[{"id":"3085"},{"id":"3086"}]}'; // your flat json    
json_object = JSON.parse(json_flat); //convert to an object

//Manipulation
json_object.page = "6"; //change values
delete json_object.total; //delete a value

json_flat = JSON.stringify(json_object); //convert back to flat
```

EDIT: Fixed some typos: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zm9rc2w/)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, you can use jQuery's json functions to edit the object.  Let me demonstrate how you might do this, with a little code:

let's take this JSON object:

```
{
 "people":[
     {"name":"Bob","score":9},
     {"name":"Joe","score":6},
     {"name":"Tom","score":7}
  ],
 "projects":[
     {"id":2347,"entries":5},
     {"id":8563,"entries":3}
  ],
 "lastUser":"Bob"
}
```

Now, let's say your server is storing that as a flat JSON file somewhere...what we'd do is load it on the client with jQuery's ajax methods, and edit it using a callback.  After manipulating the object, we'll (for demonstration purposes) immediately send it back to a server-side script, which will presumably overwrite the current flat file:

```
$.getJSON(/*path to JSON file here*/,function(response){
    response.lastUser="Tom"; //This is where the sample manipulation occurs.
    $.post(/* path to server-side script*/,response,function(){
      alert("Object Saved");
    });
});
```

Hope that helps in understanding the pattern involved!

Comment: The manipulation is demonstrated in the line `response.lastUser="Tom";
`. Modify the JSON object directly then send it back :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON data can be directly manipulated in javascript after parsing. (See Brad's comment on your question). To send the updated data back to server you can use $.post. Now, doesn't this solve your problem? If not, then please explain your problem in more detail.